# Running Python script through PHP

Tags: php, python, twisted

It is a follow-up a question to my earlier post.

I have developed a chat program using `twisted` in Python. I would like to integrate into a PHP script and be able to run through the browser.

The chat program would open a HTML window.

I could run it using `PHP5` command in the terminal and is working fine. However, when I call the PHP script through the browser it does not work.

Any idea what is missing.

EDIT : I am not getting any error on the browser, however, the python script is not running ,

Here is my PHP code :

```
$unique_no = 1234;
$unique_name = "Kiran";

$command = '/usr/bin/python /var/www/php_program/chat.py ' . $unique_no  . ' ' . $unique_name ;

shell_exec($command);
```

Thanks
Kiran

Comment: Do you have PHP configured in your web server (ie mod_php or php-fpm).  If its working on the terminal it sounds like PHP is installed on the server, but may not be configured quite right.

Comment: @fullybaked, I am not sure, I am not an expert, Any idea how to configure it.. ?

Comment: When you call the PHP script in a browser, do you get any errors? blank white page? code in plaintext?

Comment: I donot get any error on the browser. Just blank white page

Comment: Ok.  As per the tag wiki add these lines to the top of your script and run again. Update your question with what errors you see `error_reporting(-1); // to enable all errors
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);`

Comment: I donot get any error from this as well. Strange

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense.  The PHP script runs on the web server.  It generates some output which gets sent to the web browser.  Then the interaction is over until the web browser issues a new request.

You won't be able to run a Python chat program in a web browser by writing a PHP program that runs the Python program.  The Python program presumably needs to get input (for example, what message does the user want to send to the chat session?) and it can't do that when you're running it like this.

To develop a web-based chat system, the chat application actually needs to be aware that it's going to run in a browser.

Take a look at [the Nevow chat tutorial](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~divmod-dev/divmod.org/trunk/files/head:/Nevow/doc/howto/chattutorial/) for one example of how you might go about developing this application.

Comment: I understand . I have a chat program developed in Python. I wanted to have a web interface or rather, the user be able to chat through the browser?